# Can't Install Pygame for Enthought Canopy using pip or easy_install?

Tags: python, pygame, pip, enthought, canopy

Alright tried all the previous suggestions as specified in similar questions asked regarding this topic on StackOverflow. But I've encountered the following problems:

1. The default package manager has no pygame package available,hence its of no use.
2. Tried enpkg method,but then it exits sending out error messages which I can't read as they vanish quickly just before the window
       closes.
3. Tried the pip and easy_install methods but they all spit out various
   errors like "Could not find any downloads specifying the
               requirements".I'm sure I haven't made any syntax mistake while
               issuing the shell commands.

Hence I wish to ask for any way to install Pygame package in Enthought canopy either completely manually or by any other way conceivable.

If possible,a precise walkthrough would be greatly appreciated.
And please don't close this question right away as it's 'NOT THE SAME' as others because I've tried the other alternatives but to no avail.

Thanks for your time!

Edit:Forgot to mention,I'm using Windows 7 ,64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS do you use? If you are using windows, try this [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)

Since your pip raise "Could not find any downloads specifying the requirements", I guess the reason is that it's not up-to-date. Try updating it.

Comment: well,its pretty n00b but how to update pip itself?And is there a way to make pip obtain the package from a particular source link that I can explicitly supply(like the bitbucket URL)?

Comment: pip install --upgrade pip? In fact, I use easy_install to install the pip package on my pc. Hope that works for you.

Comment: And have a look at this http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/reference/pip_search.html

Answer (score 0):

I have one non_conventional Idea, just install the pygame for for your python which you just installed in your C:\ drive and then copy the pygame module in the which is found in the python27\Lib\sitepackages\pygame then paste it in the site-packages of the canopy